# Данные не дописываются в .xls файл на java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Пишу небольшой проект и не могу **дописать** данные в excel файл. Когда создается новый файл, то все заносится, а дописать никак не получается.
 Может кто сталкивался? Подскажите. 
Использую Apache POI. Ну, и, собственно, код класса.
Заранее благодарен.

```
  public class ExcelWorker {
// В этом файле будут храниться все зарегистрированные спортсмены.
private String path = new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"\\All_sportsmen.xls";
// создание самого excel файла в памяти
private HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
// создание листа с названием "Просто лист"
private Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Все спортсмены");
File file = new File(path);

/*****************************************************************************/
public void writeIntoExcel (ObservableList<Person> personDataList){
    /* TODO записывать и дозаписывать данные в файл*/

    for (int i = 0; i < personDataList.size(); ++i){
        Person person = personDataList.get(i);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(person.getId());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(person.getName());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(person.getAge());
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(person.getKind());
    }


    if (!file.exists()) {
        file = new File(path);
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            workbook.write(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
            workbook.write(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так вы их **не дописываете**, у вас же цикл записи с ноля `for (int i = 0;` так что ваша программа правильно работает.

Comment: Да, я в курсе. Но он даже не перезаписывает, что должно было бы быть, по идее.

Comment: Может вам пройтись  по ячейкам, и если там пусто, запоминать ее  и начинать записывать, как вариант. но это не самое лучшее решение

Comment: Пробовал. Не дописывает. Файл в размере растет, а данных нет. Открывая его, получаю только первую внесенную строку при создании файла. И размер его сразу становится таким, как после первого создания.

Comment: @Sergei пробуй сохранять в другой файл и проверь. у библиотеки иногда бывают глюки

Comment: В каком смысле "в другой файл"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так вы получаете последнюю используемую строку и потом прибавляете нужное

```
    int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < personDataList.size(); ++i){

        Person person = personDataList.get(i);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount + i);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(person.getId());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(person.getName());
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(person.getAge());
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(person.getKind());
    }
```

**UPD**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook wb = getWorkbookFromFile("C:\\temp\\1.xlsx");

    XSSFSheet sheetAt = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    int rowCount = sheetAt.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Row row = sheetAt.createRow(rowCount + i);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("gusi sudi " + i);
    }

    saveWorkbookToFile(wb, "C:\\temp\\3.xlsx");
}
}

public static XSSFWorkbook getWorkbookFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(filePath);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(f));
    return workbook;
}

 public static void saveWorkbookToFile(XSSFWorkbook wb, String outputFile) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile));
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

[image: Картинка]

второй прогон 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приведите обновленный код, так как у меня получилось записать

Comment: Не помогает. Пробовал. Файл даже не перезаписывется, не говоря уже о том, чтобы что-то туда дописать. =(

Comment: @Sergei обновил ответ. посмотрите, обновите ваш код и посмотрите на результат

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую - отпишусь. Но Вы здесь используете библиотеку для работы с форматом .xlsx.
Но в принципе, это не проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Действительно рабочий пример. Он копирует из одного файла во второй, а мне над одним файлом колдовать надо...
Но это, я думаю, поправимо.

Comment: @Sergei да и в один файл тоже копирует. как на второй картинке

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
// обновляем файл с помощью OutputStream
private static void appendUsingOutputStream(String fileName, String data) {
    OutputStream os = null;
         try {
            //в конструкторе FileOutputStream используем флаг true, 
            //который обозначает обновление содержимого файла

            os = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName), true);
            os.write(data.getBytes(), 0, data.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но такое решение не подходит. Т.к. данные в поток подаются из класса Workbook из Apache POI.